# Java.io.FileNotFoundException "URL"

Tags: android

I'm trying to create and android app that can pay through credit card using master card api. I' following this tutorial  ->>https://developer.mastercard.com/portal/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14876685  but it says that the url was not found.

this is the codes i used:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.submit)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String endPoint = "https://api.mastercard.com/payments/v1/purchase?Format=XML";
                EditText cardNumberInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardNumberInput);
                EditText expirationMonthInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.expirationMonthInput);
                EditText expirationYearInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.expirationYearInput);
                EditText cvvInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cvvInput);
                EditText cardHolderNameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardHolderNameInput);
                EditText amountInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountInput);

                final double amount = Float.valueOf(amountInput.getText().toString());
                final String currency = "USD";
                final String companyId = "ComID";
                final String companyPassword = "ComPass";
                final String messageId = "001";
                final String settlementId = "011";
                final String cardHolderName = cardHolderNameInput.getText().toString();
                final String accountNumber = cardNumberInput.getText().toString();
                final String expiryMonth = expirationMonthInput.getText().toString();
                final String expiryYear = expirationYearInput.getText().toString();
                final String securityCode = cvvInput.getText().toString();
                try {
                    // Send data
                    URL url = new URL(endPoint);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter request = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                                // Create the XML to post
                    request.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                    request.append("<PurchaseRequest>");
                    request.append("<MerchantIdentity>");
                    request.append("<CompanyId>");
                    request.append(companyId);
                    request.append("</CompanyId>");
                    request.append("<CompanyPassword>");
                    request.append(companyPassword);
                    request.append("</CompanyPassword>");
                    request.append("</MerchantIdentity>");
                    request.append("<Reference>");
                    request.append("<MessageId>");
                    request.append(messageId);
                    request.append("</MessageId>");
                    request.append("<SettlementId>");
                    request.append(settlementId);
                    request.append("</SettlementId>");
                    request.append("</Reference>");
                    request.append("<Amount>");
                    request.append("<Currency>");
                    request.append(currency);
                    request.append("</Currency>");
                    request.append("<Value>");
                    request.append(Double.toString(amount));
                    request.append("</Value>");
                    request.append("</Amount>");
                    request.append("<FundingCard>");
                    request.append("<CardholderName>");
                    request.append(cardHolderName);
                    request.append("</CardholderName>");
                    request.append("<AccountNumber>");
                    request.append(accountNumber);
                    request.append("</AccountNumber>");
                    request.append("<ExpiryMonth>");
                    request.append(expiryMonth);
                    request.append("</ExpiryMonth>");
                    request.append("<ExpiryYear>");
                    request.append(expiryYear);
                    request.append("</ExpiryYear>");
                    request.append("<SecurityCode>");
                    request.append(securityCode);
                    request.append("</SecurityCode>");
                    request.append("</FundingCard>");
                    request.append("</PurchaseRequest>");
                    request.flush();

                    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(conn.getInputStream());
                    Node transactionResponseNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("TransactionResponse").item(0);
                    // Test for approval.
                    String response = transactionResponseNode.getNodeValue().trim().toUpperCase();
                    Log.d("**********Response", ""+response);
                    if (response.equals("APPROVED") == true) {
                        request.close();
                        String text = "The payment processed successfully.  PHP" + amountInput.getText().toString()
                                    + " was charged to the account.";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.show();
                    } else if (response.equals("DECLINED")) {
                        String text = "The payment was declined.";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    } else if (response.equals("ERROR")) {
                        String text = "Error Processing Payment.";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    String text = "Error";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    String text = "Error";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    String text = "Error";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    String text = "Error";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

any thoughts will help me a lot. Thanks.

this is what log cat says:

```
05-22 11:20:58.129: D/**********Error2(1424): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.mastercard.com/payments/v3/purchase?Format=XML
```

Comment: Whatever the reason, you certainly shouldn't be doing network operations in a GUI callback method.

Comment: As @EJP says, you shouldn't do this on the main UI thread, even for testing. Anyway, what's the exact error that you get? I see that the page uses OAuth, but I don't see anything in your code that's doing an OAuth authentication.

Comment: I put what log cat says. I just follow the link of tutorial that I posted above. Where did you saw the OAuth authentication?

Comment: hit the endpoint url with your browser

Comment: At what line does that Exception occur?

Comment: the tutorial that I followed don't explain that OAuth authentication. Maybe that's what causing the exception. I thinks the exception occur in this line  URL url = new URL(endPoint);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
OutputStreamWriter request = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 0):

**-** Its always better to do the **UI work on UI thread**, and **Non-UI work on Non-UI thread**, but from `Android's Honeycomb` version its a LAW.

**-** So do your network call using **background thread**.

**-** Either use `Thread` to do the network call and then put the data on the UI thead using `Handler` or use what is called as **painless threading** in Android, `AsyncTask`.